# Adding a color over a photo to load into an ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap

```
Android Studio 2.0 Preview 4
```

I am trying to add a blue transparent overlay color to an existing couplePhoto.jpg and display in a `ImageView`.

This is the effect I am trying to get, like google `newsstand` app.
[image]

This is my current photo that I am trying to change, but each time the photo is loaded into the ImageView nothing has changed. 
[image]

I think the best way of doing this is to use a transparent color that will overlay the photo.

Using the following color with some alpha that will overlay onto the photo.

```
<color name="colorBackgroundShape">#99303F9F</color>
```

Here are my attempts below.

/* Attempt 1 */

```
ivBackground.setColorFilter(R.color.colorBackgroundShape, PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
ivBackground.setColorFilter(R.color.colorBackgroundShape);
ivBackground.setImageBitmap(bitmapCouple);
```

/* Attempt 2 */

```
Bitmap bitmapCouple = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.couplePhoto, options);
bitmap.eraseColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBackgroundShape));
ivBackground.setImageBitmap(bitmapCouple);
```

/* Attempt 3 */

```
Bitmap bitmapCouple = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.couplePhoto, options);
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapCouple.getWidth(), bitmapCouple.getHeight(), bitmapCouple.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
canvas.drawColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBackgroundShape));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapCouple, 0, 0, null);
ivBackground.setImageBitmap(bitmapCouple);
```

/* Attempt 4 */

```
Bitmap bitmapCouple = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.couplePhoto, options);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.drawColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBackgroundShape));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapCouple, new Matrix(), null);
ivBackground.setImageBitmap(bitmapCouple);
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Put the imageView in a relative layout and add a view over the imageView, then add tinted color to view

Comment: use relative layout and add two image view ,first for image and second for blue color

Comment: `imageView.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));` Also check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html) mate, very useful in your use case.

Comment: masking concept may help for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first try was closest to truth. In this case you can set anything to ImageView and then apply color filter (mine is transparent_black).

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(daBitmap);
        PorterDuffColorFilter greyFilter =
                new PorterDuffColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent_black), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

        imageView.setColorFilter(greyFilter);
```

Comment: You should play a bit more with  PorterDuff modes.

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    />
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgVie"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="Your color"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sub optimal to overlap two views. Why not use the setColorFilter method here?

Comment: how relative layout gonna help in this??

Comment: when we use relative layout second imageview will set over first imageview , and put transparent color in background in second imageview

Comment: There are several ways of 'doing' something - as a programmer you should strive to create optimal solutions. Sorry but the above is not an optimal solution as it causes a useless overdraw

Comment: @Skynet I have other solution also  by using masking concept.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), place.getImageResourceId(mContext));

Palette.generateAsync(photo, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
  public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
    int bgColor = palette.getMutedColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    holder.placeNameHolder.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
  }
});
```

By using generateAsync(...) to generate a color palette in the background, you’ll receive a callback when the palette has been generated in the form of onGenerated(...). Here you can access the generated color palette and set the background color of holder.placeNameHolder. If the color doesn’t exist, the method will apply a fallback color — in this case, android.R.color.black.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FrameLayout with two imageviews in it. In one load your image and in other load in the other imageview